# Programming on future hardware?

Tags: 64-bit, hardware, multicore

I want to practice programming code for future hardware. What are these? The two main things that come to mind is 64bits and multicore. I also note that cache is important along and GPU have their own tech but right now i am not interested in any graphics programming.

What else should i know about?

-edit- i know a lot of these are in the present but pretty soon all cpus will be multicore and threading will be more important. I consider endians (big vs little) but found that not to be important and already have a big endian CPU to test on.

Comment: what language? assembler multi-thread? or PHP? it makes a big difference

Comment: How is that *future* hardware?  I have it today.  If you want future hardware, build algorithms that execute on a DNA molecule in massively parallel wet chemistry structures.  That's the future.

Comment: I want to practice eating a future lunch...

Comment: seems everyone is stuck on the word "future". maybe you should edit your post to say emerging technologies.

Comment: How *far* into the future are we talking?

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to dive into a "mainstream" OS that has full 64 bit support, I suggest you start coding against the beta of Mac OS X "Snow Leopard" (codename for 10.6). One of the big enhancements is Grand Central, which is a "facility" for developers to code for multicore systems. Grand Central should distribute workload not only between core, but also to the GPU.

Also very important is the explosion of smart devices such as the iPhone, Android, etc. I strongly believe that some upcoming so-called "netbooks" will rely on OS such as Android and iPhone OS, and as such knowing how to code against their SDK, and knowing how to optimize code for mobile devices is very important (e.g. optimizing performance graphic or otherwise, battery usage).

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation for future :)

- nVidia [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html)
- nVidia [Tegra](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_tegra_apx_us.html)

Or you can focusing on ray tracing.

Comment: +1 for CUDA. Definitely worth looking at. 100+ processor cores beats 4. :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't foretell the future, but one aspect to look into is something like the [CELL processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_processor) used in the PS3, where instead of many identical general purpose cores, there is only one (although capable of symmetric multithreading) plus many cores that are more specific purpose.

> In a simple analysis, the Cell processor can be split into four components: external input and output structures, the main processor called the Power Processing Element (PPE) (a two-way simultaneous multithreaded Power ISA v.2.03 compliant core), eight fully-functional co-processors called the Synergistic Processing Elements, or SPEs, and a specialized high-bandwidth circular data bus connecting the PPE, input/output elements and the SPEs, called the Element Interconnect Bus or EIB.

[CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) are similar in that you separate your general purpose code and high performance computations into separate parts that may run on different hardware and language/api.

Answer (score 2):

64 bits and multicore are the present not the future.

About the future:
Quantum computing or something like that?

Comment: How do you program for something that doesn't really exist yet?

Comment: You can at least have a look at the theory, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP

Comment: There are simulators of quantum computers. Its possible to start learning they principles, so in the future you could be able to code assemblers for that.

Answer (score 2):

How about learning [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)? It's a massively parallel processing language based on C. It's similar to nVidia's [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) but is vendor agnostic. There are no major implementations yet, but expect to see some pretty soon.

As for 64 bit, don't really worry about. Programming will not really be any different unless you're doing really low level stuff (kernels). Higher level frameworks such as Java and .NET allow you to run code on 32 bit and 64 bit machines. Even C/C++ allows you to do this (but not quite so transparently).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Oli's answere (+1) and would add that in addition to 64-bit environments, you look at multi-core environments.  The industry is getting pretty close to the end of the cycle of improvements in raw speed.  But we're seeing more and more multi-core CPUs.  So parallel or concurrent programming -- which is rilly rilly hard -- is quickly becoming very much in demand.

How can you prepare for this and practice it?  I've been asking myself the same same question.  So for, it seems to me like functional languages such as [ML](http://www.smlnj.org/), [Haskell](http://haskell.org/), [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_programming_language), [Arc](http://arclanguage.org/), [Scheme](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/scheme/), etc. are a good place to begin, since truly functional languages are generally free of side effects and therefore very "parallelizable".  [Erlang](http://erlang.org/) is another interesting language.

Other interesting developments that I've found include

- The [Singularity](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2008-03/episode-88-singularity-research-os-galen-hunt) Research OS
- Transactional Memory and Software Isolated Processes
- The many Software Engineering Podcast episodes on concurrency.  (Here's [the first one](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2006-04/episode-12-concurrency-pt-1).)
- This article from ACM Queue on "[Real World Concurrency](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1454462)"

Answer (score 0):

Of course this question is hard to answer because nobody knows what future hardware will look like (at least in long terms), but multi-threading/parallel programming are important and will be definitely even more important for some years.

I'd also suggest working with GPU computing like CUDA/Stream, but this could be a problem because it's very likely that this will change a lot the next years.